# Java to Excel: How to get value from main class to excel class in column B?

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, apache-poi

**Excel: I want to take the variable value from "name", "number" and "country" from main class to excel class? Instead of column B: "Johan Svenson" 250 and "SWE"**

**Main class**

Take value from "Name, "Number" and "country" from main class to excel class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainProgramPA {

private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private static List<Contestant> scoreboard = new ArrayList<>();
private static String[] heptathlon = { "100 m hurdles", "High jump", "Shot put", "200 m", "Long jump",
        "Javelin throw", "800 m" };
private static ScoreCalculator calc = new ScoreCalculator();
private static String mainEvent = "Heptathlon";
//private static Excel excel = new Excel();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    contestantInput();
    resultInput();
}   

private static void contestantInput() {
    int contestants = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (contestants < 40) {
            System.out.println("Input the contestants name. Or input Exit to stop inputting contestants.");
            String name = scan.nextLine();

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Input the contestants countrys alpha-3 code.");
            String country = scan.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Input the contestants number.");
            int number = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());

            Contestant competitor = new Contestant(name, number, country);
            scoreboard.add(competitor);
        } else {
            break;
        }

        contestants++;
    }

}

private static void resultInput() {
    System.out.println(
            "The result should be measured in seconds (running), metres (throwing) or centimetres (jumping). \n");

    if (mainEvent.equalsIgnoreCase("Decathlon")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < decathlon.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < scoreboard.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("Input the result " + scoreboard.get(j).getName() + " got on the " + decathlon[i]
                        + " event. Or write exit to stop the program.");

                String input = scan.nextLine();

                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                    i = 15;
                    break;
                } else {
                    double result = Double.valueOf(input);
                    int score = calc.eventScoreCalculation("Decathlon", decathlon[i], result);
                    scoreboard.get(j).addSportEvent(decathlon[i], score, result);
                    System.out.println(score);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Input scoreboard if you want to see the scores. Input anything else to continue.");
            String choice = scan.nextLine();
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scoreboard")) {
                ConsoleOutput.printResultTable(scoreboard);
            }
        }
    } else if (mainEvent.equalsIgnoreCase("Heptathlon")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < heptathlon.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < scoreboard.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("Input the result " + scoreboard.get(j).getName() + " got on the "
                        + heptathlon[i] + " event. Or write exit to stop the program.");

                String input = scan.nextLine();

                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                    i = 15;
                    break;
                } else {
                    double result = Double.valueOf(input);
                    int score = calc.eventScoreCalculation("Heptathlon", heptathlon[i], result);
                    scoreboard.get(j).addSportEvent(heptathlon[i], score, result);
                    System.out.println(score);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Input scoreboard if you want to see the scores. Input anything else to continue.");
            String choice = scan.nextLine();
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Scoreboard")) {
                ConsoleOutput.printResultTable(scoreboard);
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Excel class**

Replace value "Johan Svenson", 250 and "SWE"

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

public class Excel extends MainProgramPA {

MainProgramPA mains = new MainProgramPA();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create workbook in .xls format
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    // For .xslx workbooks use XSSFWoorkbok();
    // Create Sheets
    Sheet sh = workbook.createSheet("Decathlon");
    Sheet sh2 = workbook.createSheet("Heptathlon");
    
    Cell cell, cell1;
    Row row, row1;
    CellStyle cellStyle, cellStyle1;
    Font font;  
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Values for Column A for Heptathlon
        Object columnA1[][] = { { "Name" }, 
                                { "Number" }, 
                                { "Country" }, 
                                { "" }, 
                                { "1. 100 metres hurdles" },
                                { "2. High jump" }, 
                                { "3. Shot put" }, 
                                { "4. 200 metres" }, 
                                { "DAY 1 TOTAL" }, 
                                { "DAY 1 PLACE" } };
        // Create Cells and Column A for Heptathlon
        int rowCount0 = 0;
        for (Object emp[] : columnA1) {
            row = sh2.createRow(rowCount0++);
            int columnCount = 0;
            for (Object value : emp) {
                cell = row.createCell(columnCount++);
                if (value instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String) value);
                if (value instanceof Integer)
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) value);
                if (value instanceof Boolean)
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) value);
                // Make the column A "bold text"
                cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                font = workbook.createFont();
                font.setBold(true);
                cellStyle.setFont(font);
                cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
            }
        }
        // Values for Column B for Heptathlon
        Object columnB1[][] = { { "Johan Svensson" }, 
                                { 250 }, 
                                { "SWE" }, 
                                { "RESULT", "SCORE", "PLACE" },
                                { "E1 Result", "E1 Score", "E1 Place" }, 
                                { "E2 Result", "E2 Score", "E2 Place" },
                                { "E3 Result", "E3 Score", "E3 Place" }, 
                                { "E4 Result", "E4 Score", "E4 Place" }, 
                                { "D1 TOTAL" },
                                { "D1 PLACE" } };
        // Create Row and Column B for Heptathlon
        int rowCount01 = 0;
        for (Object emp1[] : columnB1) {
            row1 = sh2.getRow(rowCount01++);
            int columnCount1 = 1;
            for (Object value1 : emp1) {
                cell1 = row1.createCell(columnCount1++);
                if (value1 instanceof String)
                    cell1.setCellValue((String) value1);
                if (value1 instanceof Integer)
                    cell1.setCellValue((Integer) value1);
                if (value1 instanceof Boolean)
                    cell1.setCellValue((Boolean) value1);
                CellUtil.setAlignment(cell1, HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            }
        }
        // Make the row 4 to "bold text" in Heptathlon
        cellStyle1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
        font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setBold(true);
        cellStyle1.setFont(font);
        row1 = sh2.getRow(3);
        cell1 = row1.getCell(0);
        cell1.setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            row1.getCell(j).setCellStyle(cellStyle1);
        // Merge cells on row 1,2,3,9,10 Column B, C and D in Heptathlon
        sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 1, 3));
        sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, 3));
        sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 1, 3));
        sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(8, 8, 1, 3));
        sh2.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(9, 9, 1, 3));
        // Autosize Heptathlon-columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            sh2.autoSizeColumn(i);
        }
        
    try {
        // Write the output to file
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("src//main//java//Deca-HeptathlonScoreboard.xls");
        workbook.write(output);
        output.close();
        workbook.close();
        System.out.println("Excel-file is Completed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to examine your access modifiers.  Remember, private classes, methods, and variables can only be referenced within the context of the class they belong to.

Additionally, a static method or variable is only initialized once, at the beginning of the code execution.

I would start by examining this section here:

```
private static List<Contestant> scoreboard = new ArrayList<>();
```

Additionally, I'm not sure how your Contestant class is built, but you should have some getters and setters there to allow you to pull contestant information.  So, you could so something like this in your excel class:

```
for (Contestant contestant : mains.scoreboard){
if (contestant.getName.equals('Johan Svensson')){
 ...do action here...
}
```

Finally, remember that declaring a variable within a loop means that variable is discarded each iteration of the loop and collected in garbage collection.  So, there is no way to access those variables themselves outside of that loop.